# File not found exception: Apache poi - dataProvider

Tags: apache-poi

---Data provider class---

```
   public class TestData {

   @DataProvider(name = "data")

   public static Object[][] getTableArray() throws Exception {
   File src = new File("‪D:/Data/Data.xlsx");

   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);//getting error for this line
   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Credentials");
    int rowcount = sh.getLastRowNum();

    String[][] cred = getCellData(sh,rowcount);
    System.out.println(cred[0][0]);
    return cred;


}

public static String[][] getCellData(Sheet sh, int rowcount){
    int ri=0,ci=0;
    Cell cell=null;
    String data[][]=null;
    int colcount = 2;
    for( ri=0;ri<=rowcount;ri++){
        for (ci=0;ci<colcount;ci++){
            cell = sh.getRow(ri).getCell(ci);
            data[ri][ci]=cell.getStringCellValue();
        }
        System.out.println(cell);
    }


    return data;
}
```

--Accessing Class----

```
public class Data {

@Test(dataProvider="data", dataProviderClass = TestData.class )

public void read(String username, String password) {
System.out.println(username);
System.out.println(password);
  }
}
```

This is my code i am getting error on the line where i have added the comment. Error is : java.io.FileNotFoundException: ?D:\Data\Data.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: You might want to check the permissions of file and ensure that they are openable by Java. Most often this problem arises due to permission discrepancies.